# Inspector Update Data Unexpected Token

Tags: soql, data, update, import

I am trying to insert the data from an excel sheet which I previously exported. I just merged two fields together. I keep getting the error message unexpected token. So I tried to not insert the whole data, just some part of. This works to a certain extent because for the rest of the data it keeps telling me the erro message. What data is not supported?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using for this import?

Answer (score -2):

In the data upload file if you have special character like "" at the begining of any text fields, please remove and try it will work. Thanks

Comment: That is not correct.  Double quotes are necessary in CSV files if the field contents contain commas.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the data you want to upload in excel file and save it as .csv format.
Then open the file in notepad and copy all the data.
Use CSV field for uploading in SF inspector tool - [image: CSV option image]

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: At face value, this shouldn't make any difference. If you're running into trouble trying to upload as an excel file, I would expect the issue would still be there if you had the same data in a CSV. This approach/workaround _can_ be an appropriate answer, but you really ought to reproduce the issue with an excel file (then try to apply your "fix" to see if it works). Including information about what the problem is and putting together an educated guess at why {insert other approach here} works would go a long way to improving this answer.